# batファイルでrobocopyを使用し、スペースを含む名前のファイルをコピーしたい

Tags: windows, batch-file

題名の通り、batファイルで robocopy を使用し、データをコピーしたいと考えています。
エラースキップやログを残したいため、ファイルのコピーにはrobocopyを利用する方向で考えております。

**現在できていること**
あるフォルダから別のフォルダへ、指定したキーワードを含む名前のファイルをコピーする

**できていないこと**
名前にスペースを含むファイルがコピーできない

例：robo を含む名前のファイルをコピーしたい

- **コピーできるファイル**
  　robo.txt、robo123.ppt
- **コピーできないファイル**
  　 robo robo.txt、robo 123.ppt

robocopyではスペースを含むファイル名の認識ができないのでしょうか。
他のやり方でコピーできる方法をご存知の方は教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

### 2020/03/23　追記

コピーしたいファイル名が事前に決まっている場合は "" でファイル名を囲えばいいと思うのですが、
フォルダ内のファイルを検索し、指定した名前を含むファイルを抽出したい場合はどうすればよいのでしょうか。　　　　　
現在、for文を使用しています。

```
rem //コピー元のフォルダパス指定　　
set fs_src=※任意のフォルダパス　

rem //抽出条件文字の指定
set name=robo　

for /r  %fs_src%  %%I in (*%name%*.*) do  robocopy ～
```

簡易的にまとめましたが、上記のようなコードを書いております。

---

### 2020/03/25　追記

アドバイス頂いたやり方で空白を含む名前のデータをコピーすることができました。

- コピー元データの保存先：fs_src
- 抽出したデータの保存先：fs_bk
- 抽出したいファイル名： name

  robocopy /s "%fs_src%" "%fs_bk%" "*%name%*.*"

現在、コピーと同時にLOGファイルの出力、ディレクトリ配下のみのコピーに挑戦中です…

```
robocopy /s "%fs_src%" "%fs_bk%" "*%name%*.*" /LOG:%logdir%\%target%_%ToDay%.txt %%~pI %fs_bk% %%~nxI
```

上記のように続けてLOGコマンドを打つと、LOGデータしか作成されず、データのコピーができませんでした。

Comment: LOGに関しては、新しく質問されてはどうでしょうか。いったん解決したのに、ゴール地点を動かすのは良くないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すいません投稿初めてなもので…
新しく質問しようと思います。

Answer (score 2):

スペースを含むファイル名をダブルクォートでくくってみてください。

"robo robo.txt"、"robo 123.ppt"

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
コピーしたいファイルがあらかじめ決まっていれば上記の方法で出来そうなのですが…
フォルダ内のファイルを検索し、指定した名前を含むファイルを抽出したい場合なのです。もう少し頑張ってみます！

Answer (score 2):

for文で処理せずともrobocopyの引数で対応出来ると思います。

```
rem //コピー元のフォルダパス指定
set fs_src=※任意のフォルダパス

rem //コピー先のフォルダパス指定
set fs_dest=※任意のフォルダパス

rem //抽出条件文字の指定
set name=robo

robocopy "%fs_src%" "%fs_dest%" "*%name%*.*"
```

Comment: `for`の`/r`オプションと同等にするために、`robocopy`の最後に`/s`か`/e`を追加しておいてください。[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Comment: 空白を含む名前のデータコピーすることができました！お二方ともありがとうございます！！
こちら応用させていただきます。
/s を使用しました。

Answer (score 1):

[`FOR`コマンドのヘルプ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)で説明されていますが、`~`を付けることで、変数を括る`"`を削除します。
その上で、改めて`"`で括ることで空白を正しく扱えるようになります。

```
for /r %%I in (*%name%*.*) do  robocopy ～　"%%~I"
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます！
"%%~I"　に書き換えてみましたがコピーすることができず…
もう少し試してみたいと思います！